# CRMCServiceClient works locally, but is refused on IIS

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, crm

We are experiencing a strange error where we are trying to establish a connection

```
using (CrmServiceClient svc = new CrmServiceClient(CRMConn))
```

It works fine when run locally in Visual Studio, however, when pushed to our IIS server, the request is immediately refused by CRM.

svc.LastCrmError returns that it "Failed to Establish CRM Connection."

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Microsoft CRM is not a regular application.
It's not completely standalone in the way most are.
When you run the application on your computer, it's running as you.
When it's run in IIS, it's run as the AppPool user by default.
So I tried fiddling with the AppPool identity and once as I set the running user to match the credentials of the user in the connection string, it worked!